Poetry init in Google Colab is running for hour
I'm trying to run langgraph using my Google Colab. So I used following command to install poetry in my Google Colab.
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
# Move in your Drive
%cd /content/gdrive/MyDrive/
# Create and move in the new project directory
!rm -rf reflection-agent
!mkdir reflection-agent
%cd reflection-agent
!pip install poetry
# Configure poetry to create virtual environments in the project folder
!poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true

But while trying to create pyproject.toml file in my directory reflection-agent, My following command !poetry init running for hours without creating pyproject.toml
Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

It could be that there is some interactivity happening with some of the operations (asking Y/N question) and you do not see this. Because there is no terminal accessible for you, you cannot enter to the prompt to response the interactive query.
Try running:
poetry init --no-interaction 

